# How to get positional arguments of shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sample Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $0
echo $1
```

Running this as

```
$ ./prog foo
```

would print:

```
./prog
foo
```

So I know how to get positional arguments in a shell program.

What I would like to figure out is how to do the same for any other shell command. Like `mv`, for example, I'd like to be able to say

```
mv file1 .file1.bak
```

But I would like to not have to type out file1 both times.

I tried the same as the shell script above.

```
$ echo a b c $0 $1 $2
```

But this printed

```
a b c -zsh
```

I thought it might just be a shell specific thing, so I ran it in `bash`.

```
a b c bash
```

TL;DR: How can I get positional arguments from a shell command in expansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

```
!^      first argument
!$      last argument
!*      all arguments
!:2     second argument

!:2-3   second to third arguments
!:2-$   second to last arguments
!:2*    second to last arguments
!:2-    second to next to last arguments

!:0     the command
!!      repeat the previous line
```

Ex:

```
echo a b c d e
> a b c d e
echo !$
> echo e
> e
echo "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> a b c d e
echo "!:2"
> echo ""b""
> b
```

These are commands to manipulate [bash history](https://devhints.io/bash#history).

Answer (score 2):

(I see you're using zsh, but I'm giving you a bash answer)

You can use [bash history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) to extract the first argument. Here, using `echo` instead of `mv` for demonstration:

```
$ echo file1 .!#:1.bak
echo file1 .file1.bak
file1 .file1.bak
```

where

- `!#` is the current line that you typed so far
- `:1` is the first argument in the current line

If you didn't need the leading dot, [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is also a good choice

```
$ echo file1{,.bak}
file1 file1.bak
```

Comment: Notice that history expansion is turned off by default for non-interactive shells. I can't even get it to work when setting `set -H` in the script, actually. Brace expansion, on the other hand, works by default.